# How to make a variable value exists based on the user login node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my node js application I have one userlogin api.Above that I created one varibale called customerid in my server side code.Now when user authentication is sucess.Iam storing his userid value in my customerid variable and I want to use that variable through out my application.

But the current issue Iam facing is ,when some one logins first time.It is working as expected userid is stored in customerid and doing related operations.But when another gets login, the first person customerid is overridden by send login customerid which should be the case .Every user should get only his relevant login userid as customerid..how can I make this work..Below is my code

```
var customerid;
app.post('/api/validate',function(req,res,callback){
customerid = '';
var datareq = req.body;
var data = {};
data.customerid = datareq.customerid;
request.post({
    url:'https://databasedata.mybluemix.net/verifycredentials',
    headers:{
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
     },
    body:data,
    json:true
 },function(err,res,body){    
    verifycreds(body);     
  });

  function verifycreds(data){
  if(data.length == 0){
    res.send("invalid username");
    window.alert('Invalid user');
   }
  else if(data.length > 0){
    if((datareq.customerid === data[0].customerid ) && (datareq.password == 
   data[0].password)){
    customerid = datareq.customerid;
    res.send("valid");
  }
   else{
    res.send("invalid");
  }
}
}
});
```

Comment: I don't understand your use case. I suppose every customer has an unique `customerId` in your system? Person A login successfully, you store his `customerId`. Person B comes along, so why should he be identified by PersonA's `custId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Install cookie parser dependency and use it.
You can set it in res cookie once and use everywhere in other API.
Like this

var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
app.use(cookieParser());    

app.post('/api/validate', function(req, res, callback) {
var datareq = req.body;
var data = {};
data.customerid = datareq.customerid;
request.post({
    url: 'https://databasedata.mybluemix.net/verifycredentials',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: data,
    json: true
}, function(err, response, body) {
    verifycreds(body, response);
});

function verifycreds(data) {
    if (data.length == 0) {
        res.send("invalid username");
        window.alert('Invalid user');
    } else if (data.length > 0) {
        if ((datareq.customerid === data[0].customerid) && (datareq.password == data[0].pa

ssword)) {
                res.cookie('customerid', datareq.customerid);
                res.send("valid");
            } else {
                res.send("invalid");
            }
        }
    }
});


app.get('/api/home', function(req, res, callback) {
    var customerid = req.cookies.customerid;
    // get customerid as like this in every call

});

In other API take that customer id as req.cookies.customerid from req.
```

Comment: Giving
          customerid = datareq.cookies.customerid;
                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'customerid' of undefined

why so ??giving cookies as undefined

Comment: You need to get it from req.cookies.customerid not from datareq.cookies.customerid

Comment: selva,Im still getting the same.cannot read property 'customerid' of undefined for cookies

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150559/discussion-between-user7350714-and-selvakumar).

Comment: Thanks a lot selva..It worked and thanks for pointing my  mistake regarding not usage of cookie parser